# Button opacity in Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android, button, opacity, transparent

I'm new in Android and I am working on a app that needs to show the buttons in this way.

[image: buttons_img]

I used `HorizontalScrollView` to demonstrate this action, but I don't know how to make transparent buttons step by step like in the picture.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I just work on HorizontalScrollView, but i need to be transparent.

Comment: you can change current view not other view so you have to work on center view

Comment: how can i do this to achive this action.

Comment: @Alek set alpha in xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Learn" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Android" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Step" />
        </LinearLayout>
```